# Multiple project makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to write a project which has a couple of modules.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
- bin
- scripts
- src
    - common (contains cpp files)
    - cuda (contains cuda cpp files)
    - cpp (contains cpp files)
```

So, my code has three "modules" - commons, cpp and cuda.
Commons are both used by cuda and c.
Now, I want to create Makefile that will be able to compile commons, then both CUDA and CPP modules and put them in "bin" directory with equivalent subdirs (cuda/, cpp/).

Is there any way to do this?

Should I create makefile for each of these modules?

How can I include common headers for cpp and cuda modules?

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask this question to ten different C++ developers you will get eleven different answers. There is no King of Makefiles sitting on the throne somewhere, proclaiming what is the right and what is the wrong way to write a Makefile. You have to make your own design decision, of this sort, based on your specific and individual situation. For myself, I use the GNU toolchain, autoconf and automake specifically, to build makefiles even for trivial projects in one flat directory. For more complicated projects, this is pretty much the only way to go for me.

Comment: CUDA recommends using [CMake](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/) instead of makefiles.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Do you know how to write a basic makefile? Where to put your headers is an entirely separate question.

Comment: @Beta yes, I know.

Comment: Then you can make a start on a makefile for this file structure. I think it breaks down into 1) finding the source files (with [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function)) and calculating the object file names, and 2) building the object files (with [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search)).

Comment: ...On second thought, vpath is not really called for. Three pattern rules will do the trick.